# Query inside NOT IN statement Doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, dql, doctrine-query

I found this sentence in the code:

```
        $dql
            = <<<DQL
SELECT u FROM AppBundle:User u
JOIN u.Roles r
JOIN u.team t
WHERE u.id NOT IN (
      SELECT user.id
      FROM GameBundle:Goal g
      JOIN g.user user
      WHERE
        g.objective = :objective
    )
  AND 
    r.profile = :sales_profile
  AND 
    r.company = :company
  AND 
    u.onlyStatus NOT IN (:status)
DQL;
```

I don't know how to works that query inside `NOT IN` sentence, help me please.

I need to know:

- What return the query inside of `NOT IN`, (data types, so on...)
- How to works a query inside of `NOT IN` (is posible ?)

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: edited, read again please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u FROM AppBundle:User u
JOIN u.Roles r
JOIN u.team t
WHERE u.id NOT IN (
      SELECT user.id
      FROM GameBundle:Goal g
      JOIN g.user user
      WHERE
        g.objective = :objective
    )
```

this means take all the users that **don't** currently have 'objective' in the 'Goal' table.

Is this what you needed ?

Comment: Don't watch out in tables relationships, I need to know that data is returned by the query inside NOT IN

Comment: all the columns 'id' from the table 'user'.